# <input> Cant fire the input event programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-input

[image: Web Form]

Hi all - I need the user to select a file from a Dialog. I then only need the path to that file. I've been looking and the only way it seems is to use the `<input>` but i can't have the user click the `choose file` button, it must be "clicked" programmatically

Any help would be useful.

***PS. THIS IS MY SECOND DAY OF ASP>NET - i also dont know javascript***

Aiden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to apply an event handler to the `change` event for the `input type="file"`, but some browsers will return the file path name to the file, some will display a dummy path (with correct file name), and others will just give the file name with no path.

EDIT: 
To click the file dialog programatically, you can hide it with css using `display: none`, and then do `$("#<%=myFileInput.ClientID%>").click();` to prompt the dialog.

Comment: Sorry Matthew where do i add it. The Language is C#

Comment: You can add the CSS using a css file, and assign a class to the `<asp:FileUpload id="myFileInput" cssclass="hiddenFileInput" runat="server" />`.  You would then hide with the following css `.hiddenFileInput { display: none; }`, and as for the jQuery, I'll leave that to you.